# UINavigationController pushing entire UIView to top left

Tags: ios, swift

I am working through 100 Days of Swift *without* the use of Storyboards and am running into some issues with the UI View almost fully being pushed under the UINavigationController. When removing the UINavigationController everything works as expected. I've attempted to add a new view, set `edgesForExtendedLayout =[]`, and adjusting the `y` of my CGRect to no avail. I am almost certain I am doing something quite goofy, but cannot for the life of me figure out what.

**Screenshot of what the view looks like:**
[image]

Expected is for the 3 buttons to be displayed starting under the navView.

**SceneDelegate.swift:**

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
      guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
      window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
      let viewController = ViewController()
      window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
      window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
      window?.windowScene = windowScene
    }
```

**ViewController.swift:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var button1: UIButton!
    var button2: UIButton!
    var button3: UIButton!
        
    var countries = [String]()
    var score = 0
    var correctAnswer = 0
            
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        button1 = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "us"), for: .normal)
        button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button1.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)
        button1.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        view.addSubview(button1)
        
        button2 = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button2.setImage(UIImage(named: "us"), for: .normal)
        button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button2.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 230, width: 200, height: 100)
        button2.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        view.addSubview(button2)
        
        button3 = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button3.setImage(UIImage(named: "us"), for: .normal)
        button3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button3.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 360, width: 200, height: 100)
        button3.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button3.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        view.addSubview(button3)
        
        countries += ["estonia", "france", "germany", "ireland", "italy", "monaco", "nigeria", "poland", "russia", "spain", "uk", "us"]
        
        
        askQuestion()
    }
    
    func askQuestion() {
        countries.shuffle()
        correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
        
        button1.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[0]), for: .normal)
        button2.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[1]), for: .normal)
        button3.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[2]), for: .normal)
        
        title = countries[correctAnswer].uppercased()
    }
}
```

Comment: On all 3 buttons, you are setting `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` ... but then you're trying to set the .frame`. Is this a really, ***really*** old course, that you're not using auto-layout constraints?

Comment: HA! Honestly, I saw this on so many examples, that I assumed it was "the correct" way as I've mainly been doing swift with storyboards or swiftui. Removing this line from all 3 buttons was the fix. If you'd like to add this as an answer vs comment, I will mark as correct. Thanks for your help @DonMag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the OP's comments...

The issue is that for each button you are setting:

```
button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

but then are trying to explicitly set the button frames:

```
button1.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)
```

You want to ***either*** use auto-layout or explicit frames. Mixing them will lead to trouble, with the UI elements not showing up where you expect them (as you have seen).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are building the view without using Storyboard. You should add constraints to place the buttons programmatically.

Add the code bellow to `viewDidLoad` func

```
button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: button1!, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Or,

```
button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

They do the same thing - programmatically adding a constraint from `button1` to top `safeArea`. You can also add constraints to button2 and button3 as you wish.